# Azure - The database [NAME] has reached its size quota

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

This morning I received an email stating my website was not working.  I'm getting an error when ever I try to write to my database.  The Error is:

The database [NAME] has reached its size quota. Partition or delete data, drop indexes, or consult the documentation for possible resolutions.

My database is only 16MB with a 2GB limit! I ran this query on the database after doing some research.

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('DatabaseName','Edition')
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DatabaseName','MaxSizeInBytes')
SELECT (SUM(reserved_page_count) * 8192)
FROM    sys.dm_db_partition_stats
```

Results were

Basic

2147483648

15777792

Obviously my database is much smaller than the max size.  Is there any other problem that may cause this to happen?

I am going to try to delete and restore the database in the mean time.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Once I restored the database, it started working again.

Comment: What is the error code you are getting with the error message?

Comment: @Shantanu I think the OP already knows that.

Comment: `SUM(reserved_page_count) FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats` is the *used* size, but it is not the size of the database file (it can grow to accommodate data that is later deleted, compressed, etc). I can create a 500 GB database file and only insert one row. Your query would suggest that my database is less than a MB, but if I'm not allowed to have 500 GBs worth of files on the drive, I'm still in trouble.

Comment: If you want to know how big the database files are: `SELECT [type_desc], size * 8192 FROM [sys].[database_files];`. You'll need to monitor this or avoid doing the kinds of things that cause unnecessary file growth.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Question is about Azure SQL Database, which is **not** SQL Server. What you suggest will simply not work on Azure SQL Database, because it is irrelevant when you consume Database as a Service. Todd has the correct query to get the size of the Database in an Azure SQL Database scenario. For more information check the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394114.aspx 
It is still unclear to me though, why would Todd have such problems. I've never experienced so. Todd, are using v.12 of the Azure SQL DB ?

Comment: @astaykov I disagree. The query I posted most certainly will work on current versions of Azure SQL Database ([here's some proof](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vA6uu.png)), and it will give an idea if the data files have exceeded the 2GB cap for the OP's service level. ([This screen shot shows that the numbers are not identical, and I am sure the variance can be much larger depending on workload](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tvUoC.png).)

Comment: @astaykov I am still using version 11. Even looking at the data use in the Azure management portal, it was only showing 16MB of 2GB.  If there are other files that come into play for the Azure SQL service. They should really include those in the usage info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just encountered similar problem (same exception message) with Azure DB last night - we have a 50 GB quota for elastic DB pool in Azure and total size of pool DB's is around 4 GB now. So i was expecting that all databases can grow as long as they reach total pool quota.

Turns out though that Azure actually handles quotas not based on what you have set in service plan for DB or elastic pool, but based on the quota property stored in DB instead:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2016/09/13/real-world-azure-sql-db-unexpected-database-maximum-size-limit/

> Specifically, when a database with a size quota explicitly lowered from the default is scaled up to a higher service objective, its size quota remains unchanged. For an administrator expecting the maximum size quota for the new service objective to be in effect after the scaling operation completes, this may be an unpleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

Is it sql db V12? If SQLDB v12, you can query sys.database_files to see the actual size of the database files. I would suggest upgrading to V12 as it brings lot of features that aren't there in earlier version of SQL offering.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue while importing a database from Azure storage into an Azure SQL server instance. While importing from Azure please make sure to set the below configuration based on your db size. Hope this helps someone.

[image]